# Margin Auto renders to Margin 0px

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I have the following css for a div :

```
#readWrite{
    width:100%;
    display: block !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

But, when I open in Chrome, the margin renders to 0px and hence the div is not centered.

[image]

How to resolve this?

If I do putmargin's exact values, it works. But no Responsiveness, obviously.

Here's a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7bp4m267/

Comment: can you show us some fiddle, it will be easier to help you

Comment: I'll add a link to th jsfiddle.

Comment: why use display: block !important if it is already a div? the default behaviour is display: block, so no need to specify it, even less to use the !important. Secondly, try adding a position: relative. 
And yea with some more code we could help you in an easier way.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. I have added a jsfiddle.

Comment: maybe i'm misunderstanding, but you want the anchors inside the div at the bottom to be centered in the page, not the div itself, right?

Comment: Exactly. That's how it should look. Meanwhile, the answer posted works. Could you explain why does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your parent div

```
#jam {text-align: center; width: 100%;}
```

and your child div

```
#readWrite {margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: Works. Could you or anyone explain why does that work?

Comment: I adapted it to your code.
first you need to specify the parent div to have everything center aligned, then you add this margin: 0 auto to do the trick;
margin: 0 auto is equivalent to margin-top: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 0;